# Re-purchasing a stock at a loss. Re:IRA's

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, capital-loss, wash-sale

I recently sold some stocks at losses, but also some at profit in a regular TD Ameritrade acct.

Can I buy those same stocks in an IRA within 30 days without affecting the loss in a regular account taxwise? My thinking is that since the IRA is a tax deferred vehicle, it is excluded from the gain-loss consideration.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 5):

If you sell a security at a loss and buy the same or a substantially identical security within 30 calendar days before or after the sale, it triggers the wash-sale.  It doesn't matter if the purchase is from dividend reinvestment or it is done in a different account whether that account be traditional or IRA.

The only way around this issue is to purchase something somewhat similar but not substantially identical (for example, SPY and IWM).

Comment: Had it been the other way, a ‘loss’ in the IRA and repurchase in taxable account, there would have been no issue. I’m thinking this is a duplicate, we’ve had to address this already...

Comment: What is a "wash-sale"?

Comment: @JTP: Possibly this question: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/62061/5458